# what is the diffrence between the major axis and the major axis that pass through the center of mass in 3D image

Tags: python

I have calculated the major axis of an irregular shape passing through the center of mass , and i found it bigger then the major axis , which seems uncorrect to me . I want to know if there's a better way to calculate the major axis of an irregular shape of 3D image